# Get SSD Host Writes in Windows via Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, ssd, smart, crystaldiskinfo

In CrystalDiskInfo, I can see how many GB have been written to an SSD. This is helpful to monitor its usage over time:

[image]

If possible, I would like to run a script automatically that pulls this information and keeps a log of it over time in a csv file. I could do this easily with Python if I had some way to pull that information from the command line.

Any thoughts on how I can get the total number of host writes on an SSD programmatically? I'm not sure how to access that number from the command line.

Comment: Smartmontools to (which are also available for Windows) were always command-line only. You can use it to get SMART values.

Answer (score 1):

Took them [ten years](https://osdn.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/ticket/23276), but as of 2020 CrystalDiskInfo [supports](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/crystaldiskinfo-advanced-features/) command line pulling of disk information:

> `/Exit`: Auto exit after updating S.M.A.R.T. information and AAM/APM status
>
> `/Copy`: Output “Edit > Copy” result to DiskInfo.txt
>
> **`/CopyExit`: Output “Edit > Copy” result to DiskInfo.txt and auto exit**

The last one gets you all the data as a text file. You can then pull the *Total Host Writes* from there with a few string manipulations, which shouldn't be difficult.